# How can a method of base class access the global variable declared in another method of the base class that has been overwritten?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Assume there are two files of Python, the first file defines a class:

File1: test1.py

```
class C1(object):
   def __init__(self):
       pass

   def method1(self):
      global v1
      v1 = "cat"
      self.method2()
    
   def method2(self):
      print(v1)
```

The second file define another class, which is derived from the first class from the first file:

File2: test2.py

```
from test1 import C1

class C2(C1):
   def __init__(self):
       super(C2, self).__init__()

   def method1(self):
       global v1
       v1 = "dog"
       self.method2()
```

The following is the test code:

```
c2 = C2()
c2.method1()
```

An error will occur:

```
NameError: name 'v1' is not defined
```

I want to overwrite the method 'method1' only, how can the global variable 'v1' in C2 be accessed by the method2 in C1?

Comment: Why are you using a global with a class? `self.v1` will do exactly what you want. (Also iirc a variable has to be defined first before you can declare it as global)

Comment: A method in the base class will be iteratively called, but some quantity need to be constant during iteration.

Comment: That is not a job for a global variable. That's a job for a parameter you pass the same value for on each iteration.

Comment: Yes, it may be solved by passing the same values as an argument for each iteration. But I want to know whether there are other methods.